# Duplicate questions in app feed

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ios-app-feed

I saw the same question posted twice one after the other in the SE iOS app feed (0.1.54).

> [image: duplicate questions]

It looks like some duplicate filtering may be in order.

This likely affect the Android app as well, but I'll leave the tag off since I can't confirm.

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, just a coincidence that same question has been selected in two categories of the feed. But +1 as I agree it looks weird.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Don't know is go as far as a feature request either though. Maybe request-for-feature-to-be-less-bug-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no guarantee the same item won't appear multiple times in your feed, we do make an effort to keep them from appearing too "close".

In effect, we look at the last hundred or so items before inserting a new one; and if it conflicts* throw it out.

Or rather, that's what *should* have been happening.  There was a bug where this logic was only applied within cross-site "hot" groups.  Duplicates like what you posted shouldn't happen in the future.

<sub>*Some types can't conflict, like blog posts, adds, and direct replies.</sub>

Comment: Sounds good. If they appear far apart, there's probably good reason for it showing up twice anyway. Thanks!