# Duplicate questions in search

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: screenshot of 1.4.4 showing duplicates]

Is there any reason why so many duplicates are shown in question search?

I've seen [this question about duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230143/274046) but the problem seems to persist. I'm new to the iPhone app so maybe this is something I'm not understanding. Any clarification appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that excerpts should be showing but aren't due to a height calculation issue.  Working on a fix right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.5.0, shipping later this week.

As Zizouz212 mentioned, the duplicate entries should be there because your search matches both questions and answers.  They shouldn't, however, be identical looking because they're supposed to have excerpts.

The problem has to do with the fact we use the same cell for questions (non-search) and excerpts (search).  When we configure the cell, we check if the it's an excerpt with a body length greater than zero and set `excerptHidden` with the following code:

```
- (void)setExcerptHidden:(BOOL)excerptHidden
{
    if (_excerptHidden != excerptHidden) {
        _excerptHidden = excerptHidden;
        self.excerptLabel.hidden = excerptHidden;
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];
    self.excerptVisibleConstraint.active = !self.excerptHidden;
    self.excerptHiddenConstraint.active = self.excerptHidden;
    // ...
}
```

The code doesn't instantly update the constraints but instead defers it until UIKit needs it.

When we calculate the height we use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:`.  This function is relatively dumb.  It does a terrible job calculating heights for multiline labels if the cell hasn't been laid out with that width (which is why automatic heights in UITableView suck) and **it doesn't update constraints if needed**.

Since the first time the height of a cell was calculated was on a question (non-search) all calculations were stuck assuming that an excerpt wouldn't be shown.  A simple `[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded]` before the height calculation fixes everything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your search is returning both questions and answers in the results. You can kind of tell by looking at the overview on the left, and finding the vote scores, and whether there is a list of answers. If it doesn't have a marker for the answer count, then it's an answer, otherwise, it's a question.

You can use the `is:question` and `is:answer` to refine your results :)

Comment: or, even shorter: `is:q` and `is:a`

Comment: That seems to be what's happening, but is this the desired behaviour? It seems redundant to list both questions and answers.

Comment: @paulvs Pretty sure that is the desired behaviour - the apps are designed to be consistent with the web UIs.

Comment: I can't say I've noticed this on the web UI, but I haven't used SO too much. Can you tell me why this would be desired? For example, what information does the older post in a duplicate pair tell us?

Comment: @paulvs Your question has to do with search, the dupe with hot network questions (they're very distinct). [Questions & Answers come up here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=branch+prediction), and using the search modifiers will refine those results to either questions or answers. The two entries in the results are different posts, even if they are in the same thread. It's in keeping with the web ui.